# Einstein Bot creates 20 cases instead of 1

Tags: visual-workflow, einstein-bots

I've created an Einstein Bot following this cookbook:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_knowledge_flow.htm

and it is *mostly* working. It follows the logic of asking questions, creating a Case when prompted, creating a Contact if they aren't in the database, etc. From what I can *see*, it looks like my second Flow (New Contact New Case in the Cookbook) is breaking when it goes to create a Contact with the Case.

I've looked over the Cookbook multiple times and I think my CompletedCaseIDEmail Variable is my issue. I have it as a Text type, should it be something else? I've also run the Debug with "Debug pause element behavior" and "Run flow in rollback mode". The middle option isn't available in my org.

The thing that I don't understand is that it does create the Contact with the details (first/last name, email, phone) and the Case with the Case subject input coming from the bot interaction. It just gets stuck, creates 20 cases instead of one and then closes the chat. I can provide screenshots of the Event Logs, my Flow, etc if that would help.

Comment: It turns out I needed to clear my chat variables after I redirected to the main menu. Because they weren't cleared, it just fired off my Actions & Flows. Got that fixed but now the cases aren't connected to the contact upon creation.

Comment: Figured it out. The Cookbook changed naming conventions in one place which made me think the ContactId field was linked to a variable, but it was for a Create Records. Silly of me to miss, frustrating that the naming conventions were changed but not mentioned.